# Loading data using hugging_face load_dataset from Common Voice is giving an error

Tags: python, voice-recognition, huggingface-datasets

I am working on a voice dataset using the Facebook [Hugging Face_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugging_Face) transformer, but I am unable to load data from the [Common Voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Voice) forum:

```
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric
common_voice_train = load_dataset("common_voice", "id", split="train+validation")
common_voice_test = load_dataset("common_voice", "id", split="test")
```

It gives the following error:

> Couldn't find file locally at common_voice/common_voice.py, or remotely at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/1.4.1/datasets/common_voice/common_voice.py.
>
> The file was picked from the master branch on github instead at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/master/datasets/common_voice/common_voice.py.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is *"The file was picked from..."* actually part of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Hugging Face lightweight datasets library to load the Common Voice repository dataset. The `id` parameter must be replaced with the builder configuration parameter, for instance, if you want to load the English dataset from the Common Voice corpus, the builder configuration parameter is `en`.

You can check the parameter on the Common Voice repository. It is prefixed where the version is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the specific path of the dataset, and the language id "en" for English, for example:

`common_voice_train = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_15_0", "en", split="train+validation")`

Here I typed "common_voice_15_0" for example. Choose the compatible version for you.